# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 31961100 byte allocation with 15257484 free bytes and 14MB until OOM

Tags: android

I am doing scaled a bit map like below

```
 Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath), 960, 730, false);
```

doing this processing i am upload a images some times i am getting below type error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 31961100 byte allocation with 15257484 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
```

Please help me how to solve?

Comment: Use a `BitmapFactory.Options` object as the second parameter to `decodeFile()`. Set `inSampleSize` on the `BitmapFactory.Options` to a value that will get you close to your desired scaled size.

Comment: Your operation would need more memory than is free. What kind of solution/help do you expect from us?

Comment: @ CommonsWare Please give me example how to use BitmapFactory.Options?

Comment: @anderas Please give me solution how to increase the memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you can use `BitmapFactory.Options` :

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inSampleSize = 2;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 960, 730, false);
```

Also you can calculate the `inSampleSize` for your bitmap by writing a custom function.

Here's google documentation : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

You Can increase the Memory allotted to your application by adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest.

**Note :** Increasing `heap` for your application doesn't considered to be a ideal solution.

Here's the extract from google that explains it,

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident
>   your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to
>   whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be
>   to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage
>   collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when
>   task switching or performing other common operations.

here's the complete link of the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html