# Camera Intent Memory Leak, No Activity Result

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm having an issue where using an intent to capture an image causes memory issues when you hit 'cancel' instead of 'okay' after the picture is taken. When hitting cancel, or back it does not return an ActivityResult. Rather it seems to just save the image in a cache, and restarts the camera activity. Problem is, on the third or fourth picture, it crashes the application and because it's not returning an activity result, I have no idea how to handle the memory leak.

I'm using this code to start the intent currently.

```
static Uri m_CapturedImageURI;
    void TakePhoto()
    {
        try
        {
            String fileName = "temp.jpg";
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            m_CapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert
                    (MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, m_CapturedImageURI);

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
        }

        catch (Exception e) { Log.d("Exception:", e.toString()); e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

But I've also tried this code, straight off android's developer section found here: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Even this, copy and pasted, produces the same issues of not returning an activity result and eventually crashes after 3-4 pictures.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782632/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-31961100-byte-allocation-with-1/32783082#32783082

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. That's about resizing a bitmap. Read the question, it's not returning an activity result and thus not gathering a bitmap.

Comment: All you need to do is, when ever user clicks on camera button at that time before opening camera just check for memory space and perform action accordingly.

Comment: The problem comes from taking a picture, hitting cancel, taking a picture, hitting cancel, taking a picture, without going back to the calling activity.

Answer (score 0):

Save path of image like this :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(mImageCaptureUri!=null)
        savedInstanceState.putString("camera_image", mImageCaptureUri.toString());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And Retrieve image path from this :

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("camera_image")) {
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("camera_image"));
        }
    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

This problem happens, Only when user goes to camera intent and by the time he captures the image the activity on which camera intent was hosted gets destroyed or recreated when user comes back from the camera intent.

Comment: It only occurs if I remain in the camera intent, take a picture, then cancel, then take a picture, and cancel. Meaning I'm not returning to the host activity. What it seems to need is to have the camera's buffer cleared after each picture. I'm just not sure how to go about that.