# Slide show with multiple image?

Tags: java, android, slideshow

I want to make app with different image on slide show and my code is **below**:

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_imageView);
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_textView);

    if (CustomAdapterList.titleForOther.equalsIgnoreCase("Vers la lune"))
    {
        imageView.setImageResource(vers[position]);
    }
    else {
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(image[position]);
    }

    textView.setText(CustomAdapterList.titleForOther + "");

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}
```

when I run my app and click on "Vers la lune" title my app crashed and error **says**:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 298650252 byte allocation with 12571136 free bytes and 238MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
```

and error is from **this** line:

```
imageView.setImageResource(vers[position]);
```

My manifest code is **below**:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true">
```

Comment: Are you using lazy loading? Also, show us more code like your `R.layout.swipe` and `vers` and the whole related java code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782632/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-31961100-byte-allocation-with-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work.
Add this

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

in your Manifest.xml file . In application tag .

Comment: There are lots of images that's why your allocation get full . Try on another device might not get this error . Or try to reduce size of images that will help too .