# FCM Notification Crashes MIUI on Foreground - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im testing the push notification with my app.
while the app is running on foreground, background or killed
there is contentIntent to handle the notification to which activity

on my HTC Desire 816

1. click on notification to launch activity when app is killed ( working fine )
2. click on notification to launch activity when app is running on foreground ( working fine )
3. click on notification to launch activity when app is running on background ( working fine )

but when i test on Xiaomi Note 4 ( MIUI 10 )

1. click on notification to launch activity when app is killed ( working fine )
2. click on notification to launch activity when app is running on foreground ( crash - App has stopped )
3. click on notification to launch activity when app is running on background ( crash - App has stopped )

Logcat:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 100000012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 82MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:624)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:457)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.createFromResourceStream(ResourcesImpl.java:1296)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:743)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:585)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:317)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:872)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1019)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:879)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1019)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:879)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
which is -> ( setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); )
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

tried changing flags, 
adding request id, and my things but no luck

```
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

   private void showNotification(String title, String body){
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.hyatna_eg.hyatna";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Hyatna Channel");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setSound(uri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Info");

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());


    }
```

It's expected to work normal as HTC 
but i don't know why giving me crash?

Comment: check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245018/6059583

Comment: check my answer here:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997581/5725622

Comment: Thanks for helping <3
fixed by adding  these lines to AndroidManifest.xml in application tag .
android:largeHeap="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be loading very high resolution image which causing `OutOfMemoryError` exception in `MainActivity`.

> It's expected to work normal as HTC but i don't know why giving me crash?

It's working on HTC because its PPI density is 267 and Xiaomi's 401.

Comment: you're right, fixed by adding these lines to AndroidManifest.xml in application tag .
android:largeHeap="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"